# How many ways can he select 5 marbles containing at least one of each color?

Tags: combinatorics

Dave has a collection of identical balls in which $5$ are blue, $5$ are red and $3$ are black. In how many ways can he select $5$ marbles containing at least one of each color?

Please any hint is useful? I always stuck in combinations

Answer (score 3):

This can be worked in a stars and bars manner because there are enough marbles to cover any scenario without running out.

First, pick one of each color, as required, and restate the question as,

> Dave has a collection of identical balls in which 4 are blue, 4 are
>   red and 2 are black. In how many ways can he select 2 marbles?

You should search for stars and bars problems.  In this case, 3 flavors, choose 2.

A similar problem would be,

> How many two-scoop ice cream dishes can you make with three flavors.

**ETA**: Here's an example:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535792/115823